# Can I know an address on another blockchain that was generated with the same key as an ETH address?

Tags: addresses, private-key, cryptography

Let's assume another blockchain (blockchain ATH) uses the same protocol to derive addresses from private keys as the one used by Ethereum.

If I see an ETH address then I know for sure that the person who controls it can generate an identical ATH address (unless the private key is held in a hardware wallet or something).

Now, suppose another blockchain (BTH) use a different protocol to derive addresses; as long as I know the one-way function used, is there a way for me to know which BTH address can be derived from the same key as a specific ETH address?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the algorithms used to derive the addresses.

For example all Bitcoin derived cryptocurrencies use the same algorithm to derive the address from the public key `RIPEMD160(SHA256(PublicKey))`. If you have the bitcoin address then you can determine the corresponding address in any bitcoin derived cryptocurrency, litecoin, dogecoin, etc. The only difference between them is the representation usually add a prefix with the coin type and a suffix with a checksum.

The same applies to ETH and ETC they both use the same algorithm to obtain addresses from the public key `B_{96,255}(KECCAK256(PublicKey))`. If you have an ETH address then it will also work as an ETC address.

To derive a ETH address corresponding to a BTC address you will have to break `KECCAK256`, which is equivalent to a primage attack to `KECCAK256` hash function, ie very unlikely in practical terms.